# hiera-eyaml undefined method `empty?'

Tags: yaml, puppet, hiera

I would like to store my node config in a .eyaml file.

```
"hieradata/node/client.puppetmaster.local.eyaml"


---
ntp::restrict:
    -
ntp::autoupdate:    false
ntp::enable:        true
ntp::servers:
     -   0.pool.ntp.org
     -   1.pool.ntp.org
     -   2.pool.ntp.org
     -   3.pool.ntp.org
```

but when I try to read a parameter with

```
hiera ntp::servers ::fqdn=puppet.puppetmaster.local
```

I get this error Messages

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/hiera-eyaml-2.0.7/lib/hiera/backend/eyaml_backend.rb:39:in `block in lookup': undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/hiera/backend.rb:76:in `block in datasources'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/hiera/backend.rb:74:in `map'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/hiera/backend.rb:74:in `datasources'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/hiera-eyaml-2.0.7/lib/hiera/backend/eyaml_backend.rb:29:in `lookup'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/hiera/backend.rb:206:in `block in lookup'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/hiera/backend.rb:203:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/hiera/backend.rb:203:in `lookup'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/hiera.rb:60:in `lookup'
    from /usr/bin/hiera:225:in `<main>'
```

When I store the config in a .yaml-File it works fine.

I hope you're able to help me =)

~Edit hiera.yaml

```
 ---
:merge_behavior: deeper
:backends:
    - yaml
    - eyaml
:logger: console
:yaml:
    :datadir: '/etc/puppet/hieradata'
    :extension: 'yaml'
:eyaml:
    :datadir: '/etc/puppet/hieradata'
    :pkcs7_private_key: '/etc/puppet/keys/private_key.pkcs7.pem'
    :pkcs7_public_key: '/etc/puppet/keys/public_key.pkcs7.pem'
    :extension: 'eyaml'
:hierarchy:
    - "node/%{::fqdn}"
    - node/common
    - fqdn/%{fqdn}
    - env/%{environment}/%{fqdn}
    - osfamily/%{osfamily}
    - lsbdistcodename/%{lsbdistcodename}
    - common
```

Comment: Can we see your `hiera.conf`? Have you made sure that `eyaml` uses the correct datasources? Note that each backend must be configured separately (even if they are not used in parallel).

Comment: `---
  1 :merge_behavior: deeper
  2 :backends:
  3     - yaml
  4     - eyaml
  5 :logger: console
  6 :yaml:
  7     :datadir: '/etc/puppet/hieradata'
  8     extension: 'yaml'
  9 :eyaml:
 10     :datadir: '/etc/puppet/hieradata'
 11     :pkcs7_private_key: '/etc/puppet/keys/private_key.pkcs7.pem'
 12     :pkcs7_public_key: '/etc/puppet/keys/public_key.pkcs7.pem'
 13     :extension: 'eyaml'
 14 :hierarchy:
 15     - "node/%{::fqdn}"
 16     - fqdn/%{fqdn}
 17     - env/%{environment}/%{fqdn}
 18     - osfamily/%{osfamily}
 19     - lsbdistcodename/%{lsbdistcodename}
 20     - common`

Comment: Thanks, but this is utterly unparseable. Please edit your question and add the information.

Comment: Uh sorry 
I've edited my question :-)

Comment: Hmm, have you tried to remove the `:extension: 'eyaml'` line? It should not be necessary and I wonder if it's actually an issue here. - As an aside, renaming to `.yaml` probably works because the `yaml` backend is active and reads the same directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to create a symlink

```
/etc/puppet/hiera.yaml -> /etc/hiera.yaml
```